# Prove that $\overline{a+b}=\bar{a}+\bar{b}$

Tags: complex-numbers

**Question:**

> Prove that $\overline{a+b}=\bar{a}+\bar{b}$

**My attempt:** I've tried this:

$\overline{a+b}=\bar{a}+\bar{b}$
$$
(x+iy)-(z+in)=(x-iy)+(z-in)=
(x-z)+(y-n)=(x+z)+(-y-n)
$$
But I just can't get the right answer, I would be glad if you could explain this to me.

Comment: How did you get the first equality in $$
(x+iy)-(z+in)=(x-iy)+(z-in)
(x-z)+(y-n)=(x+z)+(-y-n)
$$???

Answer (score 2):

$a = x + i y$ and $b = u + iv$, then
\begin{align}
\overline{a + b} & = \overline{x + i y + u + i v} \\
& = \overline{x + u + i(y + v)} \\
& = x + u - i(y+v) \\
& = x - iy + u - iv \\
& = \bar a + \bar b
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have defined $a=x+iy, b=z+in$.  Then $\overline {a+b} = \overline {x+iy+z+in}=x-iy+z-in=\overline a + \overline b$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=x_1+y_1i$ and $b=x_2+y_2i$, where $\{x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Thus, $$\overline{a+b}=\overline{ x_1+x_2+(y_1+y_2)i}= x_1+x_2-(y_1+y_2)i=x_1-y_1i+x_2-y_2i=\overline{a}+\overline{b}.$$
Done!