# Division with remainder identities: $\overline{a+b}=\bar a +\bar b $ and $\overline{ab}=\bar a \bar b$

Tags: integers

I am reading a text on finite fields and got stuck on a little side note of the introductory part. I hope I am adding enough context, if not let me know. $p$ is a prime number and $a,b \in \mathbb Z$.

> For every integer $a$ we denote with $\bar a\in {0, ..., p-1}$ the
> remainder of $a$ when divided by $p$. That means $\bar a$ is a uniquely
> determined number in ${0, ..., p-1}$ with $a=kp+\bar a$ for a $k\in
>  \mathbb Z$. (This has already been proven) ... *It is easy to prove that $\overline{a+b}=\bar a +\bar b$ and $\overline{ab}=\bar a \bar b$*.

Unfortunately this is not easy for me. My try:

Let $a=kp+\bar a$ and $b=lp+\bar b$ with $k,l \in \mathbb Z$. $$a+b=kp+\bar a + lp+\bar b;$$ $$a+b=(k+l)p+(\bar a+\bar b).$$

Thus $\overline{a+b}=\bar a +\bar b$. However, it may well be that $\bar a +\bar b$ larger than $p$, so this does not work.

While looking for an answer I found this question: [Prove that $\overline{a+b}=\bar{a}+\bar{b}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473404/prove-that-overlineab-bara-barb)  But this is not helping me.

Comment: Hello :) Your $\bar{a}$ does not need to be less than $p$. It only says there is a representative $a'$ with $0\leq a'<p$. Maybe one has to distinguish between the coset and the representative. Commonly, you set $\bar{a}:=\{a+kp\mid k\in \mathbb Z\}$ and then your equation holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right and the book is wrong.

The best you can get with the definition of $\bar a$ you quote is
$$ \overline{a+b} = \overline{\bar a + \bar b} \qquad\qquad
\overline{ab} = \overline{\bar a \bar b} $$
or alternatively
$$ \overline{a+b} = \bar a \boxplus \bar b \qquad \qquad \overline{ab} = \bar a \boxdot \bar b$$
where $\boxplus$ and $\boxdot$ are *modular* addition and multiplication operations on $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$.

The modular operations are more commonly defined to work on *residue classes* instead of on the particular representatives $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$. It feels plausible that the author of your text was confusing what they were doing with a notation where $\bar a$ means $\{np+a\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$, the residue class containing $a$. But even so, that requires an explicit definition of how to add and multiply such classes.

Comment: Thank you! How do you show that $\overline{a+b} = \overline{\bar a + \bar b} \qquad$ holds?